# elastic search multiple types search

Tags: types, elasticsearch

I dont know if elastic search have poor documentation or i am just searching in the wrong places. The thing i am trying to do is that i want to search a specific index but different type with different quires but one result back. for example:

I have an index called `beta` and two types inside the index test1 and test2, i want to query the two types with one query:

type test1

```
 {
        "query": {
            "fuzzy_like_this": {
                "fields": ["LastEditorID"],
                "like_text": "Test1",
                "min_similarity": 0.1,
                "max_query_terms": 5
            }
        }
    }
```

type test2

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this": {
            "fields": ["LastEditorID"],
            "like_text": "Test2",
            "min_similarity": 0.1,
            "max_query_terms": 5
        }
    }
    }
```

and get the results in one peace I mean one object.I also prefer to specify the type in the query no in the GET request

I am new to elastic search so please anymore just ask.

UPDATE: what i need is something like this but that doesn't work

```
[{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this": {
            "fields": ["user"],
            "like_text": "Haider",
            "min_similarity": 0.1,
            "max_query_terms": 5
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "type": {
            "value": "typetest"         
        }
    }
},
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy_like_this": {
            "fields": ["user"],
            "like_text": "Haider",
            "min_similarity": 0.1,
            "max_query_terms": 5
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "type": {
            "value": "typetest"         
        }
    }
}

]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a filter to your query and filter on `_type` field.

Does it help?

Comment: Thank you for the replay, as i said i am new with ES so did you mean something like that `{
 "query": {
  "fuzzy_like_this": {
   "fields": ["LastEditorID"],
   "like_text": "C4446476-15E6-E111-9ECB-B7C5971D170A",
   "min_similarity": 0.1,
   "max_query_terms": 5
  }
 },
 "filter": {
  "type": {
   "value": "test1"
  }
 }
}` because that didn't work

Comment: an example would help greatly